# Solve didn't give the right solution

Tags: equation-solving

I've got a pretty simple equation set here but I cannot seem to solve it correctly.

```
T[0] = 1;

T[1] = 2;

f[i_] := T[i] - T[i + 1] == T[i + 1] - T[i + 2]

c = And @@ Array[f, 3, 0]

Solve[c, T[4]]
```

The answer only gave me the following

```
-1 == 2 - T[2] && 2 - T[2] == T[2] - T[3] && 
T[2] - T[3] == T[3] - T[4]
```

Instead of solving for T[4], so where did I messed up ? Thanks!

Comment: `Eliminate[c, T[3]]` gives `T[2] == 3 && T[4] == 5`

Comment: What happens if you ask it to solve for three of the variables?

Comment: I would like see the answer to that question as well:)

Comment: @Fang  Well, try it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you have the recursion t[i+2] = 2*t[i+1]-t[i]. Shifting this back two timesteps allows a standard form:

```
t[i_] := 2 t[i - 1] - t[i - 2];
t[0] = 1;
t[1] = 2;
```

which can be solved for any i:

```
t[#] & /@ Range[10]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using recursion (NOTE that recursion can go either up or down)

```
Clear[t]

t[0] = 1;
t[1] = 2;
t[i_Integer?Positive] :=
  t[i] = 2 t[i - 1] - t[i - 2];
t[i_Integer?Negative] :=
  t[i] = 2 t[i + 1] - t[i + 2];

list1 = t /@ Range[-5, 5]

(*  {-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}  *)
```

The general solution is

```
FindSequenceFunction[
  Thread[Range[-5, 5] -> list1]][i]

(*  1 + i  *)
```

You can use [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) to find the general solution more directly

```
Clear[t]

t[i_] = t[i] /.
  RSolve[{t[0] == 1, t[1] == 2,
     t[i] == 2 t[i - 1] - t[i - 2]},
    t[i], i][[1]]

(*  1 + i  *)

list2 = t /@ Range[-5, 5]

(*  {-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}  *)
```

Approaches are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

`Reduce` or `FindInstance` handles your problem. I switched to lower case `t` as it is recommended not to use uppercase letters at the beginning of a symbol.

```
t[0] = 1;
t[1] = 2;
f[i_] := t[i] - t[i + 1] == t[i + 1] - t[i + 2]
c = And @@ Array[f, 3, 0]
```

produces

```
-1 == 2 - t[2] && 2 - t[2] == t[2] - t[3] && t[2] - t[3] == t[3] - t[4]
```

and then

```
Reduce[c, t[4]]
```

gives

```
t[3] == 4 && t[2] == 3 && t[4] == 5
```

and

```
FindInstance[c, {t[2], t[3], t[4]}]
```

gives

```
{{t[2] -> 3, t[3] -> 4, t[4] -> 5}}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. I was quite confused about the use of Eliminate and Reduce but now I can see the difference. Thanks for the help.